# Karate Chops? (Uses and practicality of knifehand techniques)

Tags: technique, karate, application

In popular culture in the West, "karate chop" became a meme, probably because it looked so exotic to people used to Western boxing.

My understanding that that the proper name for the technique is "knifehand", and Chinese styles also employ them.  But what are they good for?

- How are knifehand strikes used in Karate and are they practical?  What are the main targets?

Are they considered "meat and potatoes" or more like the sauce?  Have these technique been used in MMA?  How often do they show up in sparring?

Comment: Heh, I was actually considering asking about this last night, I think because I was rereading the question about chops to the neck.

Comment: The issue with knifehand is you have to either condition the hand *a lot* or you have to strike with the wrist instead.

Comment: @HuwEvans not if you intend to knock someone out with a knife hand to the neck. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcaOr1TBA1w

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think other people will be able to provide better answers, as most of my experience is in other styles, but [this poster](https://www.ju-sports.de/gym-dojo-ausstattung/accessoires/poster-deko/poster-karate-striking-points), which has been on the walls of almost every Karate-based school I've ever attended, gives a list of targets for the knifehand.

[image: Karate Striking Points poster] (click to enlarge)

Namely, they match the knifehand with:

- inner forearm
- inside and outside elbow
- side of neck
- clavicle
- vastus externas
- groin

That list does not include the windpipe and back of the neck, both targets that were suggested to me when doing Shotokan Karate.

Comment: Excellent answer.  (Wondering if the windpipe and back of the neck are excluded for being particularly dangerous...)  Also wondering how it is applied to the groin—my first though would be to an attacker behind you, using a down/backward chop.